# How to temporarily hide model relations attributes with Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have read how to [temporarily hide model attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json).
I would like to temporarily hide a model relation attribute.

For instance

```
{
    "slug": "google-chrome",
    "name": "Google Chrome",
    "description": {
         "text": null,
         "created_at": "2016-12-05 12:16:38",
         "updated_at": "2016-12-05 12:16:38"
}
```

What is the syntax for hiding the description.created_at only in this query?
In my SoftwareController I have

```
public function show(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $models = Software::query();

    $model =
        $models
        ->where('slug', $slug)
        ->firstOrFail()
        ->makeHidden([
            'description.created_at',
        ]);

    return $model;
}
```

This syntax does not seem to work?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`makeHidden()` doesn't support dot notation.

You should call makeHidden on your related model:

```
$model = $models
        ->where('slug', $slug)
        ->firstOrFail();

$model->description->makeHidden('created_at');
```

Note that this will only work when you have a single result. If you want to do this on a Collection, you must iterate on the itens and run makeHidden for each item you have.